# Oracle Execute Immediate not escaping quote?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECLARE
  v_column_exists number := 0;  
BEGIN
  Select count(*) into v_column_exists
    from user_tab_cols
    where upper(column_name) = 'MyCoolColumn'
      and upper(table_name) = 'MyCoolTable';

  if (v_column_exists = 0) then
      execute immediate 'alter table MyCoolTable add (MyCoolColumn varchar2(255))';
      execute immediate 'update MyCoolTable set MyCoolColumn = 'NULL'';
  end if;
end;
/
```

Unfortunately I get the oracle error

> ORA-06550
> PLS-00103 Encounter Symbol "NULL" when expecting .....

on the line:

```
execute immediate 'update MyCoolTable set MyCoolColumn = 'NULL'';
```

I know I am inserting the word "Null" and not a null value. I am adding this column to an existing table and need to make it Not Null and a primary key with two other primary key columns. If I remove the problem line the statement executes fine.

Am I not properly escaping the 'Null'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
execute immediate 'update MyCoolTable set MyCoolColumn = ''NULL''';
```

you need two quotes to escape the 1st ' , then triple quotes for the end, one for the escape, and the second for the string temination.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way to handle this:

```
execute immediate q'[update MyCoolTable set MyCoolColumn = 'NULL']';
```